# Comparing feasible region of LP

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let's say I have two different systems of convex constraints, A and B. With A an n by 5 matrix and b an m by 5 matrix. I would like to know how much the feasible regions differ. Are there any methods for doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "how much feasible regions differ"?  Geometrically, or in terms of the solution to the LP?

Comment: Geometrically. I can find the difference in terms of the solution of the LP by solving the LP twice, one with each set of constraints.

Comment: I was assuming you meant it for all $A$ and $B$, not two specific ones. To look at the geometric difference, there's a metric on the set of bounded, compact sets of a metric space called the Hausdorff distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).